# Manga/manhwa in which a baby is found in a forest and raised by three gods and one goddess

Tags: story-identification, manga

A god found a baby in a forest and the other two gods and the one goddess raise him to be a hero, then the day comes and the gods don't want him to leave.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, do you recall any other details about the characters or story? If so, please edit the question to include them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this ***[A Boy Raised by Gods Will Be The Strongest](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/a-boy-raised-by-gods-will-be-the-strongest)***...?

> Will, an abandoned child, was brought to Table Mountain by the God of Thousand Theophanies, then educated by the God of Sword, Healing, and Magic. He grew up to be a surprisingly brave, strong and sweet boy. When he turned fourteen, a blind priestess Lunamaria visits the mountain and asked him to save the world. Thus the journey begins...!

A baby boy is found drifting alone in a small boat by the God of Omnipotence, Reus. Reus transforms into an eagle and carries the boy to Table Mountain, where he's raised by the God of Swords, Ronin, the Goddess of Health, Miria, and the God of Magic, Vandal, who teach him their skills and give him the name Will.

> [image: A Boy Raised by Gods Will Be The Strongest, chapter 1, page 14.]
>
> [image: A Boy Raised by Gods Will Be The Strongest, chapter 1, page 15.]

Shortly before Will's fifteenth birthday, a blind priestess comes to the mountain and asks him to go on a journey with her to save the world. His overprotective parents are initially suspicious of her and reluctant to let him leave, but ultimately give him their blessing to do so after he passes a series of trials they set for him.

Comment: thank you so much i can't find it os thank you